# Using Beautifulsoup gives a ResultSet object upon instantiation

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to use `beautifulsoup`, but when I instantiate it with an html object, it is saying that it is a ResultSet object and any methods I try to run fail with an AttributeError.

```
bs = BeautifulSoup()
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(bs) == type(soup)

False
```

I have tried with response.content and gotten the same result, and haven't been able to find this exact issue yet from other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating an empty BeautifulSoup object with the first line of your code. Your second line of code returns an empty resultset as a result. Instead, you want to do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```